# Recover listview scroll position in fragment after screen rotation

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Please trust me, i really already tried so many things i found on the web, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803569/listview-within-fragment-cant-save-scroll-position) and the listview.onSaveInstanceState(), but unsuccessfully.
I'll post some of my methods:

```
    public class ChatFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    OnItemLongClickListener {

private String target;
private ListView listview;
private EditText edittext;
private Conversa conversa;
private MainActivity activity;

private int position_recover = -1;

public static final String LISTPOSITION = "listposition";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);

    target = getArguments().getString(MyService.EXTRA_TARGET);

    // esse target é passado com o mTag no contrutor do tablistener.
    // no tablistener ele precisa ser igual definido na tab da activity, mas
    // daqui pra baixo eh target

    if (target.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.TITLE_TAB_CHAT)) {
        target = MyService.CANAL;
    }

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    conversa = MyService.getConversa(target);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

    edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.chatinput);

    listview.setAdapter(conversa);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    // LISTENER QUE RECEBERA O "ENVIAR" DO TECLADO DO ANDROID
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(...);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        position_recover = savedInstanceState.getInt(LISTPOSITION);

    }

    return view;
}

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setHint();

    if (position_recover != -1) {
        listview.setSelection(position_recover);
        position_recover = -1;
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putInt(LISTPOSITION, listview.getLastVisiblePosition());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

After rotation, if listiview was on start position, it stills on start position, else it goes to the end.

Please help me cause i'm on it has been a while.